# Perl script not found when executed from a different directory than the current one

Tags: perl, ksh

I am using perl64 on Windows 10 with UWIN installed.

I wrote a perl script, sv2jb.pl, which runs fine when invoked under ksh by just typing its name, and when it is in the current directory.

I then created a subdirectory of my home directory called "scripts", moved that script there, added its full path to the $PATH environment of ksh. Now when I invoke sv2jb.pl from any other directory than where this script is (by just typing the script's name), this is the message I get back:

```
$ sv2jb.pl
Can't open perl script "//C/users/me/desktop/scripts/sv2jb.pl" : No such file or directory
```

But this is exactly where that file is...

If I invoke it so from the home directory (in which the scripts directory is):

```
$ scripts/sv2jb.pl
```

it works fine...

Also, if I cd to that directory, and invoke sv2jb.pl:

```
$ cd scripts
$ sv2jb.pl
```

it runs correctly.

I am at a loss to understand what is wrong:

1. The script itself is OK, since when invoked from its directory it runs. FYI, its first line is:
       #!//c/perl64/bin/perl.exe
2. The $PATH variable is OK, since the error message shows that ksh located the file (while saying it can't find it).

Comment: Beware line endings.  Can you show output of `head -1 sv2jp.pl | od -c`?

Comment: I had already checked it, it is OK (see below). Also, if it weren't, the script wouldn't work regardless of where it is invoked from. Here is od's output: `#   !   /   /   c   /   p   e   r   l   6   4   /   b   i   n /   p   e   r   l   .   e   x   e  \r  \n  \r  \n`

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with "UWIN" for windows10.  Do you have a reference for it?  You're not talking about Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Comment: No no, see here about UWIN: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UWIN

Comment: Let me add this: the PATH environment contains such directories as `/usr/bin`, etc., and the binary executables that are in these directories can be invoked without a problem from anywhere else. I put my script in /usr/bin and tried to invoke it: same reply, it said it could not find `/usr/bin/sv2jb.pl`... (I had invoked it without the full path, so it does find it!).

Answer (score 2):

Not familiar with UWIN, but I'm going to assume it's similar to cygwin in that it provides a library layer to run on top of windows.

When you invoke the script, it's found in the PATH, opened by the program loader, examined to find the #! line, the executable binary is found and exec()ed, with the script name passed in as the first argument.

The problem is that the binary is consistent with being the ActiveState perl, a windows application.

I suspect that when the script is in the current directory, perl is run with the script name passed in as a relative program (something like `perl sv2jb.jpl`).  But when it's elsewhere, a full pathname is given (something like `perl //C/users/me/desktop/scripts/sv2jb.pl`).

But the windows binary doesn't understand the path that's being passed to it.  You can see this by invoking it directly from a windows command prompt.  You should see this happen:

```
C:\Perl64\bin>perl //C/users/me/desktop/scripts/sv2jb.pl  # what is running
Can't open perl script "//C/users/me/desktop/scripts/sv2jb.pl

C:\Perl64\bin>perl C:/users/me/desktop/scripts/sv2jb.pl   # Changed to windows-style filepath
[...program runs....]
```

I can reproduce the same behavior with cygwin/Win10 and ActiveState Perl.

Basically, setting a windows binary as the executable for a unix script has odd problems.  With cygwin, I'd suggest that you instead used the package perl instead of the windows one.  I don't know if that's a possible solution for UWIN.

Otherwise, you can call the windows perl, but you must pass in a windows-style path to the script explicitly.